# How to avoid page break after \part entry in ToC with memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, memoir

I am using the `memoir` class for a document with many chapters and parts.
In the ToC sometimes there is a page break between the name of `\part` and the name of the next chapter.

```
Table of Contents

Part I
1. Chapter ........... 5
2. Chapter ........... 10
3. Chapter ........... 15

Part II 
1. Chapter ........... 20
2. Chapter ........... 25
3. Chapter ........... 30

Part III
‹page breaks here›
```

I tried to find out in the [memoir](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) documentation, but as a beginner I did not understand how to avoid the page breaking after a new part.

As Steven explained to me [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134016) (look there for an example), I certainly have to use `needspace`, but I don't now how.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17071/how-can-i-force-toc-not-to-end-with-a-chapter ?

Comment: Didn't find that before. to add `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}` before Part III works, but I would prefer a solution, that avoid such a page break in the header.

Comment: try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123109/prevent-pagebreak-inside-table-of-contents-entry, mutatis mutandis

Answer (score 3):

One of the (IMO) best ways to fix something like this is to make the space above `\part` and `\chapter` entries flexible, that usually solves the problem. Otherwise use the

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
\part{title}
```

Not sure what you mean by "but I would prefer a solution, that avoid such a page break in the header"

```
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{2.25em plus 0.5em minus 0.5em}
% default is 1em plus 0pt
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{1.0em plus 0.5em minus 0.25em}
% default is 1em plus 0pt
```